# How can I load up / stress test GPU on Android device?

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsl

I've been searching and trying stuff for a few days with no luck. I have an embedded system using a Snapdragon SoC. It is running Android 5.0 and using openGL ES 3.0. It is not a phone and does not have a display, but I am able to use Vysor Chrome extension to see and work with the Android GUI.

Since it's not a phone and in a rather tight physical package, and I will eventually be doing some intensive encoding/decoding stuff, I am trying to test thermal output and properties under load. I am using Snapdragon Profiler to monitor CPU utilization and temperature.

I have been able to successfully load up the CPU and get a good idea of thermal output. I just made some test code that encodes a bunch of bitmaps to jpeg using standard Android SDK calls (using the CPU).

Now I want to see what happens if I do some GPU intensive stuff. The idea being that if I leverage the GPU for some encoding chores maybe things won't get so hot because the GPU can more efficiently handle some types of jobs.

I have been reading and from what I gather, there are a few ways I can eventually leverage the GPU. I could use some library such as FFMPEG or Android's MediaCodec stuff that uses hardware acceleration. I could also use openCV or RenderScript.

Before I go down any of those paths I want to just get some test code running and profile the hardware.

What's a quick, easy way to do this? I have done a little bit of openGL ES shader programming, but since this is not really a 3D graphics thing, I am not sure I can use shaders to test this. Since it is part of the graphics pipeline, will openGL allow me to do some GPU intensive stuff in the shaders? Or will it just drop frames or crash if I start doing some heavy stuff in there? What can I do to load up the GPU if I try shaders? Just a long while loop or something?

If shaders aren't the best way to load up GPU, what is? I think shaders are the only programmable part of openGL ES. Using RenderScript can I explicitly run operations on the GPU or does the framework just automatically determine how to run the code?

Finally, what is the metric I should be probing to determine GPU usage? In my profiler I have CPU Utilization but there is no GPU utilization. I have available the following GPU metrics:

[image: gpu metrics 1]
[image: gpu metrics 2]

Answer (score 0):

> but I am able to use Vysor Chrome extension to see and work with the Android GUI.

If you have Chrome working on the platform with a network connection, and don't care too much about what is being rendered then https://www.shadertoy.com/ is a quick and dirty way of getting some complex graphics running via WebGL.

> I could use some library such as FFMPEG or Android's MediaCodec stuff that uses hardware acceleration. I could also use openCV or RenderScript.

FFMPEG and MediaCodec will be hardware accelerated, but likely not on the 3D GPU, but a separate dedicated video encoder / decoder.

Comment: "FFMPEG and MediaCodec will be hardware accelerated, but likely not on the 3D GPU, but a separate dedicated video encoder / decoder."

oooh that's interesting! I had not thought of that. So my testing of the GPU might be moot. I will eventually be doing video and picture encoding and I have found that really CPU intensive stuff causes things to get too hot, so that's why I was looking at using the GPU to do some on the fly encoding. If the out of box encoders are using some other onboard chip and not the GPU, this still may keep things cooler, but I may be wasting time with this GPU test.